# Displaying name and selecting id on select for Twitter Typeahead

Tags: twitter-typeahead

I am trying to implement twitter typeahead into my project, having remote as the source.  I am able to make the connection between the front end query text and the sql.  The return response looks like this:

```
[
 {
    id: 1,
    name: 'user one'
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   name: 'user two'
 }
 ..
]
```

The typeahead displays the matching items but it includes the id along with the names in the selection, instead of just the name.  Second, I want to get the id value on select but the :select always gives the name value instead of the id.

here is my code:

```
           var source = new Bloodhound({
                datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                remote: {
                    url:"{{ path('user_typeahead') }}"+'?string=%QUERY', // twig path
                    wildcard: '%QUERY',
                    filter: function (results) {
                        // Map the remote source JSON array to a JavaScript object array

                        return $.map(results, function (result) {
                            return {
                                value: result
                            };
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            // Initialize the Bloodhound suggestion engine
            source.initialize();

            $('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
                   display: 'value',
                   source: source.ttAdapter(),
                   limit:5,
                   highlight: true,
                   hint: true
                });

            $('#typeahead').bind('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion) {
                console.log(suggestion);
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

1. Display should be set to the property of the json object. `display: 'id'`
2. Chain the custom event. Access your id from `suggestion.id.`

   `$('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
                  display: 'id',
                  source: source.ttAdapter(),
                  limit:5,
                  highlight: true,
                  hint: true
               }).bind('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion) {
               console.log(suggestion);
           });`